# What is BinaryOperation, what are all its std:: implementations and how to use it with std::transform to get maximum

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++17

I have three naked memory arrays and would like to perform element-wise binary operations on them so that x_array = A_array op B_array. They are templated inside an function

```
T* A_array, B_array, x_array;
```

and I assume T is an numeric type, typically `float, double or uint32_t`. I have the following code so far:

```
if(ARG.multiply)
{   
    std::transform(A_array, A_array + ARG.frameSize, B_array, x_array, std::multiplies());
} else if(ARG.divide)
{   
    std::transform(A_array, A_array + ARG.frameSize, B_array, x_array, std::divides());
} else if(ARG.inverseDivide)
{   
    std::transform(B_array, B_array + ARG.frameSize, A_array, x_array, std::divides());
} else if(ARG.add)
{   
    std::transform(A_array, A_array + ARG.frameSize, B_array, x_array, std::plus());
} else if(ARG.subtract)
{   
    std::transform(A_array, A_array + ARG.frameSize, B_array, x_array, std::minus());
} else if(ARG.max)
{   
    std::transform(A_array, A_array + ARG.frameSize, B_array, x_array, std::max());
} else if(ARG.min)
{   
    std::transform(A_array, A_array + ARG.frameSize, B_array, x_array, std::min());
}
```

I end up with the following errors in case of min and max:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'max'
        std::transform(A_array, A_array + ARG.frameSize, B_array, x_array, std::max());
                                                                           ^~~~~~~~
 note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument '__l', but no arguments were provided
    max(initializer_list<_Tp> __l)
    ^
note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
    max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&);
    ^
note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
    max(initializer_list<_Tp> __l, _Compare __comp)
    ^
 note: candidate function template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 0 were provided
    max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare);
```

It can be fixed as follows by using lambda:

```
std::transform(A_array, A_array + ARG.frameSize, B_array, x_array, [](T i, T j) {return std::min(i, j);});
```

1. Is there `stl::` implementation of min and max, which can go without lambda? Can I somewhere find what all in the standard library is inherited from std::BinaryOperation and what all from std:: will act as an instance of it?
2. Shall I use lambda function instead? And how the lambda becomes
   instance of `std::BinaryOperation` when it was surely not inherited from it?
3. Why people use `std::back_inserter(x_array)`, I guess    it is not necessary on naked array. Will it have some effect if I use it?

Comment: "*I end up with rather cryptic errors regarding min and max*" And what are those errors?

Comment: What are the errors? Can you provide a [mcve]? Can you give an example of what the `max` and `min` operations would do to an array?

Comment: The problem is that [std::min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and std::max have 4 overloads each, and the compiler doesn't know which one you want to use. Also, `minus()` creates an object, while `max()` is a function call.

Comment: You should give some more code, so that we can provide a proper answer. What are the types of the array elements? That's important. But you need to provide either a functor or a purpose-built function or lambda in place of the generic `std:max()` and `std::min()`.

Comment: ... something along the lines of `[](int a, int b) { return std::max(a, b); }` (assuming `int` elements).

Comment: `std::multiplies` (and other) is a class (type). `std::max` is a function. `X()` means different things for types and functions. Notice, that lambda `[](int a, int b){ return divides(a, b); }` does __not__ work.

Comment: Aside: `std::BinaryOperation` is not a thing. The template parameter rendered `BinaryOperation` in the reference can be instantiated with an infinite variety of things. `std::plus` and `std::minus` don't share any base class.

Answer (score 0):

For example std::plus is a class. So this expression `std::plus()` in the algorithm call yields an object (functor) of the class that is used within the algorithm.

On the other hand `std::min` and `std::max` are functions. So an expression like this `std::min()` is a function call without specifying arguments. Moreover the function is overloaded.

You should use a lambda expression like for example

```
std::transform(A_array, A_array + ARG.frameSize, B_array, x_array, 
    []( const auto &x, const auto &y ) { return std::min( x, y ); }
```